# How to extract files from Qlik Sense website

Tags: download, qliksense

I have executed this code in the Qlik website app

```
   myTable:
    LOAD *
    FROM [lib://DataFiles/orgFile.xlsx]
    (ooxml, embedded labels, table is sheet1);
    
    Store * from myTableinto [lib://DataFiles/transFile.qvd];
```

The qvd file is stored in the DataFiles web folder but I don't know how to reach it. I whould like to download de qvd file or save it in C:/somefolder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataFiles` is the name of a data connection. If you have the right permissions (edit data connections in the Hub and/or read data connection in QMC) you can see the connection string. The connection will be the path (local or network) where the qvds will be stored.

The path of all folder data connections is from the point of view of Qlik. If new data connection is created with path `C:/some-folder` then this path will be actually pointing to the `C:` on the server where the reload is being performed.

Folder data connections can be set to network path as well. The only "condition" is Qlik to be able to access the network path. Technically you can create folder on your machine and share it and then create data connection (or edit an existing one) to write the qvd files there. The obvious downside is that if your machine is offline then any apps, relying on this data connection, can't be reloaded.

Probably the easiest approach, in your case, is to find the connection string of `DataFiles` data connection.

If you have access to QMC (and have the correct permissions there) you can see the connection string:

[image: data connections sidebar]

[image: data connections list]

[image: data connection props]

If you have the edit data connection permissions you can find the path by trying to edit the data connection itself:

[image: data connection hub]

[image: edit data connection]

**P.S.** And again ... the connection path is from Qlik's point of view. So in my example `C:/QlikData/Apps` folder is actually on the QS server itself and not my machine.